# How to insert a new slideshow on click of a link on the same page in the background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel=stylesheet href="styles.css" type=css/text>
</head>


<style>
body{

background-color: #111;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

background-position: center;
}

.right {
margin-top: 20px;
margin-right: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    border:3px solid #8AC007;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>

<style type="text/css">
.show{display:block;}
.hide{display:none;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showImg()
{
var obj=document.getElementById('pic1');
obj.className = 'hide';
var obj1=document.getElementById('pic2');
obj1.className = 'show';
}
</script>

<div>

<script language="JavaScript1.2">
var bgimages=new Array()
bgimages[0]="pic1.jpg"
bgimages[1]="pic2.jpg"
bgimages[2]="pic3.jpg"
//preload images
var pathToImg=new Array()
for (i=0;i<bgimages.length;i++){
pathToImg[i]=new Image()
pathToImg[i].src=bgimages[i]
}
var inc=-1

var bgimagesTour=new Array()
bgimagesTour[0]="pic4.jpg"
bgimagesTour[1]="pic5.jpg"
bgimagesTour[2]="pic6.jpg"
//preload images
var pathToImgTour=new Array()
for (j=0;j<bgimagesTour.length;j++){
pathToImgTour[j]=new Image()
pathToImgTour[j].src=bgimagesTour[j]
}
var incr=-1
</script>
</div>

<div class="show" id="pic1"  >ofjvhkjnvf
<script language="JavaScript1.2">

function bgSlide(){
if (inc<bgimages.length-1)
inc++
else
inc=0
document.body.background=pathToImg[inc].src
}

if (document.all||document.getElementById)
window.onload=new Function('setInterval("bgSlide()",3000)')

</script>

</div>

<div class="hide" id="pic2" >kflaksjfvnksfvn
<script language="JavaScript1.2">

function bgSlideTour(){
if (incr<bgimagesTour.length-1)
incr++
else
incr=0
document.body.background=pathToImgTour[incr].src
}

if (document.all||document.getElementById)
window.onload=new Function('setInterval("bgSlideTour()",3000)')

</script>

</div>

<font color="white">
<div class="right" >
<u><a href="#" onClick="showImg();">Tourism</a></u>&nbsp<u><a>Festival</a></u>&nbsp<u><a>Food</a></u>&nbsp<u><a>Music</a></u>&nbsp<u><a>Blog</a></u>&nbsp<u><a>Suggestion</a></u></div>
```

In the above code I have 2 slideshows and two different functions. If I try to run the same code for a single image it would work.
eg:

```
<li><a href="#1" onclick = "showImg()" value= "Picture1" title="Home">Home</a></li>
<img id="Picture1" src="/home/sharvil/Project/new/map.gif" class="show">
```

It also works on anything that is written just after the  tag of the 1st slideshow to change the text written just after the  tag of the 2nd slideshow. Although, it doesnt seem to be working for the javascript written at the respective positions. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

What your `showImg` function doing is, it will always hide your `pic1` identifier(ID) div and will always show the `pic2` ID div.

Also you have set `pic1` ID div to show and `pic2` ID div to hide when page loads. So you will be able to see only one slide at a time.

Comment: I want to replace one slideshow with another.
Hence, when the page loads there is only one slideshow to be seen.
But on click of a link it changes the 2nd slideshow to be shown and the 1st slideshow to be hidden. Works perfectly for single image or any text content.